# untrusted application launcher in 17.10

Tags: 17.10

When I install the software I cannot see the correct icon.When i double click,it is displaying application launcher and I marked it as trusted.Now I can can see the correct icon.

[image]

Can you please help me in displaying proper icon of the software before clicking as trusted as project requirement.

Comment: **To close voters:** I added an image to clarify. This is a new problem with 17.10 of which i as well would love an answer to. Not unclear at all.

Answer (score 0):

1. `cd ~/Desktop`
2. (In Terminal) `sudo chown yourusername DaVinci\ Resolve.desktop`
3. Right Click Icon and make sure "Allow executing file as a program" is ticked or enabled.
4. Double click the icon and it will change the actual program Icon and launch.

Comment: The command in step 2 looks a bit confusing - What is it supposed to do?